# Struggling with If Statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, logical-operators

I have problems of understanding values of variables in PowerShell and I check them with if statements.

```
$LDAPDirectoryService = '10.10.XXX.XXX:389'
$DomainDN = 'o=Enterprise'
#$LDAPFilter = '(&(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf=cn=alc-01-Planung-rw,ou=KT,o=enterprise))'

$LDAPFilter = '(&(cn=alc-01-Planung-rw))'

$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Net')

$LDAPServer = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection $LDAPDirectoryService
$LDAPServer.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Anonymous

$Scope = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope]::Subtree
$AttributeList = @('*')

$SearchRequest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest -ArgumentList $DomainDN,$LDAPFilter,$Scope,$AttributeList

$groups = $LDAPServer.SendRequest($SearchRequest)
$groups

if ($groups -eq $null) {"No Group found"}
if ($groups -eq " ") {"No Group found"}

foreach ($group in $groups.Entries) {
    $users = $group.attributes['member'].GetValues('string') 
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        Write-Host $user
    }
}
```

I want to check if the group exists and then if users are existing in this group. I tried many statements but none of them seem to work. 
It's not null or blank, even when nothing is written down in the console.

This is what I got when I use group which doesn't exist:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anybody show me a solution?

Comment: Try `if ($groups.matcheddn -eq $null) { 'no group found' }`

Comment: Unfortunately it remains the same

Comment: I think `$groups` is an array, so you could test the `Count` property with `if ($groups.Count -eq 0)` or `if (!($groups.Count))`. Cannot test this myself right now though..

Comment: Its not an array "$Groups.Entries" remains 1 under all circumstances

Comment: what do you get back when a group DOES exist?

Comment: The [doc for SendRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.sendrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_LdapConnection_SendRequest_System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_DirectoryRequest_System_TimeSpan_) says that it returns a `DirectoryResponse` object, so assigning it to a variable called `$groups` seems misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PowerShell are you running? Why are you not using the built-in AD group cmdlets for this or are you not using ADDS but some other LDAP service?

Or you may be on OSX/Linux and are using PSCore, which the ADDS/RSAT cmdlets are not there, well, not yet?

For your goals of …

> I want to check if the group exists and then if users are existing in
>   this group.

… On Windows, with PowerShell 3x or higher, it's really only this...

```
# Get all AD groups and all members of each group
Clear-Host
(Get-ADGroup -Filter '*').Name | 
%{
    "`n*** The members of $PSItem are as follows: ***`n"
    If((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $PSItem).Count -ge 1)
    {
        (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $PSItem).SamAccountName
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "$PSItem does not exist or has no members."
    }
}


# Filtered
Clear-Host
((Get-ADGroup -Filter '*').Name -match 'Domain Admins|Domain Users' ) | 
%{
    "`n*** The members of $PSItem are as follows: ***`n"
    If((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $PSItem).Count -ge 1)
    {
        (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $PSItem).SamAccountName
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "$PSItem does not exist or has no members."

    }
}
```

Using your LDAP approach though... How about this...

```
'Administrators','Distributed COM Users' | 
ForEach {
    # Define LDAP search root, the Global catalog of the domain
    $sLDAPSearchRoot = "LDAP://$((Get-ADDomainController).IPv4Address):389"

    # The Groupname to looking for
    ($sGroupName = "$_")

    # The LDAP query - query string
    $sSearchStr = "(&(objectCategory=group)(name="+$sGroupName+"))"

    # Get the search object
    $oSearch = New-Object directoryservices.DirectorySearcher($oADRoot,$sSearchStr)

    # Looking for the group
    $oFindResult = $oSearch.FindAll()

    # On success, get a DirectoryEntry object for the group
    $oGroup = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($oFindResult.Path)


    # And list all members
    If (($oGroup.Member).Count -ge 1) 
    { 
        $oGroup.Member | 
        %{($oMembers = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($sLDAPSearchRoot+"/"+$_))}
    }
    Else
    { Write-Warning -Message "$($oGroup.Member) does not exist or has no members"}
}
```